# Table's width not expanding fully on some window resolutions in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser

The following document looks like it should in Firefox, Opera, Safari and even IE6 and later(!), but not Chrome - at SOME resolutions (I'm guessing uneven widths?) http://jsfiddle.net/4BEvL/1/

The problem is that the menu doesn't expand as much as the content div, so it'll leave a gap at the edge:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/3tGwD.png]

Setting a MAX-width for the `#container` div instead strangely fixes the problem, but that's not the result I want; besides, it'll look pretty bad in IE6 (which I have yet to drop support for) since it doesn't support max/min-* CSS rules.

Can I fix this for Chrome somehow (without using CSS hacks)?

Comment: Looks fine from here (looking at jsFiddle with Chrome). Is your browser Zoomed in at all?

Comment: No, it's at 100%. Try putting the code in a file and open that instead, jsFiddle might shrink the page a little. Also, what version of Chrome are you on?

Comment: Saved it in a file, still looks fine. Version 23.0.1271.97 m

Comment: And you're sure you've tried dragging the sides of the Chrome window  to resize it (to be specific)? I was just on 23.0.1271.91 m myself, but updating to .97 m didn't help.

Comment: Resizing the window, there was one small instance where I see what you are talking about...I am not sure if it is fixable though :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `display:table;` to the `#container` div.

(It compromises a few things on my site though).

Answer (score 0):

Your table is inside #container which is set to 85% width of the body. So setting table to 100% width will only let the table expand to 85% of that. Percentages are always percent of its positioned parent which, in this case, is #container. But container is also constrained to be a minimum 800px wide so it won't shrink any further when you decrease the width.

Comment: The minimum width has nothing to do with this. We are only talking about one pixel here, and the problem only occurs 50% of the time (window sizes). Have you even tried looking at it in Chrome? Either way, I solved the problem already - I just can't accept my answer yet.